# How are negative and positive energies related?

Tags: energy

People often seem to talk about negative energy as a kind of anti-energy, a bit like a financial debt being thought of as negative money. Is that correct, or is the relationship between positive and negative energies more like that between positive and negative electric charges, just two opposite polarities? Is the relationship different in different situations, such as gravitational potential, squeezed light, the Casimir effect, etc.?

Comment: All of these are just ways of talking that _describe_ certain calculations. In the calculation itself, however, positive and negative just have the same meaning as in positive and negative numbers, i.e. they differ by a minus sign.

Comment: As always, the most useful ways of talking just depend on the situation, but the math remains the same. It's the same old negative numbers you learned in grade school.